# Why does the onClickListener not work anymore in this example?

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to create a GridView in android following the example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), just with **buttons** except images. Here is the code I have changed:

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] filesnames = {
            "File 1",
            "File 2",
            "Roflcopters",
            "File 1",
            "File 2",
            "Roflcopters",
            "File 1",
            "File 2",
            "Roflcopters",
            "File 1",
            "File 2",
            "Roflcopters"
    };

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filesnames.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btn;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            btn = new Button(mContext);
            btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 85));
            btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else {
            btn = (Button) convertView;
        }                       

        btn.setText(filesnames[position]);
        // filenames is an array of strings
        btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
        btn.setId(position);

        return btn;
    }
}
```

and, of course, I slightly changed the main java code as I have named this adapter and the activity differently:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_route);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.selectroute_view);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(SelectRoute.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine so far, except that when clicking on one of these buttons I do not get a toast-message. I do not see any error - so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android when a two views which nested need a focus or clickable by default (`Button` or `ImageButton`) the Android System will/may favour one. For your case remember you have `AdapterView`(this case its `GridView`) has a layout that is also Clickable that means those  `Button`s so It does not know whether you want to click the row of the GridView or the `Button` inside the row (if you do not know in android rows of grid view and list view are clickable even without a button inside them).

So what happens is the Android System does not know what you want to click the row or the `Button` inside the row. And unfortunately the clickable behaviour has been given to the `Button` and not the row which you appear to set `onItemClickListener` which is not working.

**So to solve your problems you have to the following alternatives:**
**1.** Remove the Button and replace it with just a `TextView`. The row will be clickable since the `TextView` wont take the focus by default like a `Button`.

**2.** Make a custom row. A row should be defined outside as an independent view via `xml` and the `Button`inside it then you will inflate it as a row for your `GridView`. And after that add the following atrributes to the `parent/root` of the view

```
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

This will block the `Button` from taking the whole focus because the `Button` will be a descendant and will be blocked. If you do not how to make a Custom `GridView` rows of multiple Views in a row use any tutorial may be [this tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html).

**3.** The last but the simplest alternative if you real love your layout and you dont want to remove your button the set `onClickListener` though it is hard to get the `View`'s (`Button`'s) position using this way. We add this in the `getView()` method of your Adapter. **Here is how:**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        btn = new Button(mContext);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 85));
        btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    }
    else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }                       

    btn.setText(filesnames[position]);
    // filenames is an array of strings
    btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
    btn.setId(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button=(Button)v;
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked "+button.getText().toString()+" with ID "+button.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    return btn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the click listener directly on the button in the adapter?

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btn;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            btn = new Button(mContext);
            btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 85));
            btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else {
            btn = (Button) convertView;
        }                       

        btn.setText(filesnames[position]);
        // filenames is an array of strings
        btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
        btn.setId(position);

        //ADD THIS, to get context just getContext from the view.
        btn.setOnClickListener...

        return btn;
    }
```

Comment: I will try, but I don't understand why it does not work like the original example...

Comment: With your suggestion I have problems with local variable accessing etc